# Apache caching only works sometimes

Tags: php, apache-2.4, cache

I'm trying to set up caching on my Apache site starting with a basic configuration that I can test a PHP script with a browser:

```
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot /var/www/cache
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
CacheMinExpire 3600
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
```

However, it only works if the page is not "redirected" in some way. For example, I'm testing this simple PHP script in the root directory called "test.php":

```
<?php
    echo date('h:i:s');
?>
```

If I go to ".../test.php" in my browser, it works: the output time doesn't change after the first visit.

If I go to ".../test", it doesn't work: the output always changes to the current time.

Two notes:

1. When it works, I see an "age" field in the cached response with an updated number of seconds since the page was first served. When it doesn't work, there is no "age" field in the response.
2. I don't have an .htaccess file in the root directory, and I haven't been able to find where Apache knows to serve the script without the "php" extension. When I test using an .htaccess file with a RewriteRule, it doesn't cache the response when it matches. Not sure if this matters.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the caching headers? I'm not very familiar with Apache, but in Nginx you have to have headers set correctly for the caching to work, and I doubt redirects have caching headers set up. Try reading [this][(https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding a couple of headers to the response, including "cache-control: max-age=3600" and "Age: 1". I could see them come through in Chrome tools, but the behavior didn't change.

Comment: Correction: When I included "cache-control: max-age=3600" in the header of the response that was redirected by the .htaccess file, it correctly returned the cache after the first time. When I included it in the header of the output of the test.php script, it still didn't work when the url didn't include the .php extension. But the .htaccess redirect was really my problem, so I'm good now. Thanks again @tim. If you want to create an Answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you need to set your caching headers correctly for page caching to work. There's a good article [here](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers/), and Apache docs [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html).

In summary of that article, you want to set the Cache-Control header. You can set etag, but the rest like pragma you shouldn't bother with.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
```

In Apache this is done with [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html), which would be configured something like this.

```
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# expire GIF images after a month in the client's cache
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
# HTML documents are good for a week from the
# time they were changed
ExpiresByType text/html M604800
```